# Mockito returns null instead of Future.successful

Tags: scala, mockito, playframework-2.3

I'm having a bit of a problem getting Mockito to return a `Future` which gets mapped in the unit under test.

The stubbed method in question is this:

```
when(urlRequest.post(any())).thenReturn(Future.successful(badOAuthResponse))
```

Where `badOAuthQuery` is a `Map` defined elsewhere and `badOAuthResponse` is a mocked `WSResponse` defined elsewhere.

The line in question where it gets called is:

```
val response = client.url(oAuthUrl).withHeaders(headers: _*).post(requestMap)
```

Where `client` is a mocked `WSClient`, with its methods stubbed elsewhere.

I've narrowed the problem down somewhere around the POST request. Stepping through the debugger shows that all the previous method calls before the `.post()` return fine, but stepping past the line, `response` is set to `null`.

The line afterwards, where the `NullPointerException` actually gets triggered, is this:

```
response.map { resp =>
```

Obviously the problem is that `response` was set to `null` in the line before, but I don't know why Mockito doesn't return a successful `Future` containing the mocked object above.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `badOAuthQuery` is *identical* to `requestMap` (i.e., calling `badOAuthQuery.equals(requestMap)` returns `true`)? I suspect it's not, and that's usually the problem when you see a mock return `null` like this (because Mockito mocks return nulls by default when you don't explicitly stub it).

Comment: Hmm, I took a look at that again, thinking that might be the problem. I tried instead doing `when(urlRequest.post(any())).thenReturn(Future.successful(badOAuthResponse))` and fixing the specifics later, but I still hit the same `null` issue.

Comment: Is `client.url(oAuthUrl).withHeaders(headers: _*)` returning `urlRequest`?

Comment: In this case, client is the wsClient mock with the following mocked methods: `when(wsClient.url(any())).thenReturn(urlRequest)
    when(urlRequest.withHeaders(any())).thenReturn(urlRequest)
    when(urlRequest.post(any())).thenReturn(Future.successful(badOAuthResponse))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem, after a lot of head scratching. It turns out that the object I was mocking (`WSRequestHolder`) has two methods called `post`: `post(body: File)` and `post[T](body: T)(implicit wrt: Writeable[T], ct: ContentTypeOf[T])`. I had assumed that my mock was set up for the latter method call, but it turns out that I needed to more explicitly call the method as follows:

```
when(urlRequest.post[Map[String, Seq[String]]](any())(any(), any())
  .thenReturn(Future.successful(badOAuthResponse))
```